# Script to automatically add items to categories based on a specific attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, category, attributes

we use magento 1.8.1ce

We have build our shops products mostly on attributes.

Now i need for a special storeview the brands in a category form too.
But i don't want to do double work when adding products.

Is there a way a script can read the attribute `manufacturer` and create/add the items to the same manufacturer in the category tree.

So like the manufacturer attribute has the options: Apple, Sony And WD
And It creates sub-categories (when not made yet) with the same name and add all items which have the the attribute

Like 
Brands -> Apple -> Apple product 1, Apple product 2 etc
          Sony-> Sony product 1, Sony product 2 etc

And a there must be a possibility to run this by cron.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Elgentos_Automanufacturers](https://github.com/elgentos/Automanufacturers) which does the following:

> This extension will create a category (which can be placed within a category of your wishes) with the manufacturers name when you save a product and can place the product directly in this category. No more manually adding your manufacturer categories or manually placing your products in those categories!

Another one would be [FireGento_DynamicCategory](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-dynamiccategory) which is not specifically tied to manufacturers.

> The module adds a new section "Dynamic Category Product Relater" at the tab "Category Products" of categories in the backend. You can define rules for products to be included in the category.
>   If a rule should be defined according to a specific attribute, that attribute needs to be enabled for "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" in its attribute configuration.